# Trigger en SQLServer 2008 para validar e impedir sobreescribir campos diligenciados

Tags: sql, trigger, sql-server-2008

Actualmente tengo un trigger el cual debe validar que si el campo notas ya está diligenciado, no debe permitir realizarle update a la fila.

Actualmente tengo este trigger, pero no me permite realizar update a la fila, así tenga el campo notas diligenciado o vacío:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*** Trigger que valida que si la tabla tiene el campo notas ya diligenciado, 
no debe permitir que se pueda sobreescribir  ****/
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[validar] ON [dbo].[produccion_clientes]
FOR UPDATE
AS
---declaramos variables, en esta caso id y notas
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @notas INT

SELECT @id = f.id
    ,@notas = isnull(f.notas,0)
FROM produccion_clientes f
JOIN inserted i
    ON f.id = i.id


DECLARE @mensaje VARCHAR(200)

/** Si el campo notas está diligenciado, debe salir un mensaje sacando error, puesto que dicho campo
ya está diligenciado ***/

IF (@notas IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    SELECT @mensaje = 'EL REGISTRO YA FUE INGRESADO'

    RAISERROR (@mensaje,11,2)

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Estás usando `isnull` para definir notas y le estás dando un valor por defecto. *Nunca* va a ser nulo (tu validación es siempre verdadera porque preguntas si es `NOT NULL`...). Más allá de eso, no sabemos el tipo de dato de la columna f.notas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios errores en ese trigger, pero básicamente buscas que no se pueda sobreescribir en la columna de notas. En tu versión actual estás validando únicamente una fila, cuando deberías validar todas las filas que se están actualizando. Además, estás asignando un valor default a la variable, por lo que nunca será nula. Por último, estás usando la tabla física en lugar de la tabla virtual `deleted`.

Una versión corregida y simplificada, podría quedar así.

```
/*** Trigger que valida que si la tabla tiene el campo notas ya diligenciado, 
no debe permitir que se pueda sobreescribir  ****/
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[validar] ON [dbo].[produccion_clientes]
FOR UPDATE
AS
/** Si el campo notas está diligenciado, debe salir un mensaje sacando error, puesto que dicho campo
ya está diligenciado ***/
IF EXISTS(  SELECT *
            FROM deleted
            WHERE notas IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @mensaje = 'EL REGISTRO YA FUE INGRESADO';

    RAISERROR (@mensaje,11,2);

    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias! Funcionó correctamente!!

Comment: @CamiloGutierrez Si la respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como respuesta aceptada